# lost doing a query against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS Table with a table join

Tags: mysql, metadata

I am trying to bring Back DISTINCT B.INDEX_NAME along with B.COLUMN_NAME..that is why i used the group by

then for each row returned I need the A.DATA_TYPE

A.DATA_TYPE returned is incorrect

```
SELECT  A.DATA_TYPE, B.INDEX_NAME,  B.COLUMN_NAME
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as A, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS as B
where B.TABLE_SCHEMA= "mySchema"
and   B.TABLE_NAME  = "myTable"
and   A.TABLE_SCHEMA = B.TABLE_SCHEMA
and   A.TABLE_NAME   = B.TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY B.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this query?  (i.e. what are you trying to find or learn about your database?)

Comment: I just want all index columns regardless of the type of index, then for each returned index get the column name and then from that get the Data type for that column. 
column names return should be distinct
on a side note I was also looking at "show INDEX FROM TABLE" but that does not return what I need either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by the `GROUP BY` clause picking a `DATA_TYPE` at random out of the multiple values being returned because you have no condition on your `JOIN`. What you need to do is restrict the number of values per column name to 1 by adding a condition to your `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.DATA_TYPE, B.INDEX_NAME, B.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS A
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS AS B
ON A.TABLE_SCHEMA = B.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
   A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND
   A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE A.TABLE_SCHEMA= "mySchema" AND 
      A.TABLE_NAME  = "myTable"
```

In PHP (with MySQLI):

```
$sql = 'SELECT A.DATA_TYPE, B.INDEX_NAME, B.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS A
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS AS B
ON A.TABLE_SCHEMA = B.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
   A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME AND
   A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE A.TABLE_SCHEMA= "mySchema" AND 
      A.TABLE_NAME  = "myTable"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) print_r($row);
```

Comment: Thank Nick, that did it

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it accepted so that other users can find it. Thanks! :)

Comment: this query run fine in my phpMyAdmin. but when I run it in my php script ($result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);) 
It returns nothing.
then on my mysqli_num_rows() 
I get  "Warning 2 - mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given "

Comment: Hi Lixo - can you edit your post with the PHP code? I have tried it on my server and it works fine...

Comment: I've edited my post with the PHP/mysqli code I am using.

Comment: i had the above already.. it dies before it even gets to mysqli_num_rows.
I don't think mysqli likes the query.... If i simplify to a single table it gets thru

Comment: That is weird, it works fine for me. Can you post your PHP code?

Comment: OK, got it to Work, Sorry about wasting your time, you have been a great help.
Turned out I was ending the query in my php code with a ")".. a Character that had no business being there.. a typo

2:15 am, i think i can go sleep now. lol

Comment: Glad to hear it. No problem asking the extra questions, it's important to me you end up with a working answer.